# Execute Ubuntu command using Laravel Schedule

Tags: laravel-8, scheduled-tasks, schedule, laravel-9, laravel-scheduler

I want to run a command to remove all files under the folder **'allfiles/'**

```
root@admin:/home/admin/allfiles# find . -name '*' | xargs rm
```

and it clears all files under **allfiles**

I want to run the same command using Laravel Schedule, I am using in this way

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{

    $schedule->exec('find . -name '*' | xargs rm /home/admin/millionfiles/')
             ->everyMinute(); 
}
```

But it does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed **'** before the directory beginning

Also try adding double quotes instead of single

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)  {
    $schedule-> exec('find . -name "*" | xargs rm ' . '/home/admin/millionfiles/')
             ->everyMinute(); 
}
```